# A variable name with "/" or "()"

Tags: r, variables, backslash

Using `RODBC` package I pulled data from access to R.
One of the names in table in access is : "JED_credit\debit (local)"

When I'm trying to refer to the cell in R I get:

```
JED_credit\debit (local)
"Error: unexpected input in "JED_credit\"
```

Comment: Where is the code that you are using to refer to that column? This should be something like `df$"JED_credit\debit (local)"`

Comment: sorry. I forgot to mention that I attached the data before.

Comment: So `detach` it and try to never use this function again, unless you have a very good reason to.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not the recommended way of defining variables, but it is working by using backward ticks.

```
> `var` <- 'test'
> var
[1] "test"
> `var/bla` <- 'test'
> `var/bla`
[1] "test"
> `var()bla` <- 'test'
> `var()bla`
[1] "test"
> `var\bla` <- 'test'
> `var\bla`
[1] "test"
```

Comment: Thank's but it shoes me this error:
`JED_credit\debit`
Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "`JED_credit\d"

Comment: Need some more lines, not just the error message. What did you do?

Comment: You'll need to escape the ``\`` with ``\\``

Answer (score 0):

There are a few characters sequences in almost all languages which have a special meaning. For example `\n` stands for a newline character.

In your regular string, the parser treats `\d` in `JED_credit\debit` as a special character sequence rather than a part of the string. To make it a part of the string, you need to escape the back slash with another`\` thus making your variable name as `JED_credit\\debit`.

Answer improvements are welcome.